# Xubuntu 14.04.05 LTS, usb wifi doesn't connect after waking up

Tags: wireless, usb, suspend, asus, wakeup

I've got this Asus wifi usb adapter (n10) which works fine except that ubuntu doesn't seem to detect it when I wake my computer up from suspend. It works fine on reboots, and when I take it out and plug it back in again it works too. If I could get it to auto-detect though, that would be much nicer. Might be worth noting that I've got Windows 8 on my hard drive too, and when waking up it detects the wifi adapter fine.

thanks for any help!

Comment: If you aren't opposed, you could try on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It might have better compatibility with the newer kernel.

Comment: Does the wireless restart if you do: `sudo service network-manager restart`?